# Java Client not receiving C# Server response TCP

Tags: java, c#, server, tcp, client

Can somebody explain to me what I am doing wrong.First time I try to implement TCP between Java and C#:

Sever code c#
`

```
public void CreateServer()
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                IPAddress addr = IPAddress.Parse(localIP);
                tcpListener = new TcpListener(addr, 5053);
                if (tcpListener != null)
                {
                    tcpListener.Start();
                    while (!end)
                    {      
                        TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                        var ip = ((IPEndPoint)tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString();
                        Console.WriteLine("Client connected from "+ip);   
                        NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(clientStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                        try
                        {
                            string request = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            Console.WriteLine("Message from client: " + request);

                            Byte[] StringToSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Server");
                            clientStream.Write(StringToSend, 0, StringToSend.Length);
                            Console.WriteLine("Sending response back");
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e);
                        } 
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.Start();
        }
```

`

Client code java
`

```
public class TCP {

    private String IP;
    private InetAddress server;
    private Socket socket;

    public TCP(String IP) {
        this.IP = IP;
    }

    protected void runTCP() {
        try {
            server = InetAddress.getByName(IP);
            socket = new Socket(server, 5053);
            System.out.println("Client connected. Listening on port 5053");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Sending data...");
            if (socket.isClosed()) socket = new Socket(server, 5053);
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            writer.print(message);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getResponseServer() {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Attempting to get response...");
                    if (socket.isClosed()) socket = new Socket(server, 5053);
                    BufferedReader mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    String mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();
                    System.out.println("Server message: " + mServerMessage);
                } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

`

Output on server I get when sending "Hello" from client to server:
`Client connected from 192.16.... Message from client: Hello Sending response back Client connected from 192.16....`

Output on client:
`Client connected. Listening on port 5053 Sending data... Attempting to get response...`
Never gets response... Why?

Tried researching but found nothing yet, tried other code but didnt work aswell...

Comment: I'm not familiar with the C# API, but I notice you flush in the Java code; does something similar happen on the C# side?

Comment: Streams, TextReaders and types derived from them in C# are IDisposable's and should therefore be used in conjunction with the `using` statement. Quite likely, since you don't dispose the NetworkStream instance nor flush it, the data you write to it still lingers in some send-related buffer and without it being transmitted yet. (Disposing of the NetworkStream - which would automatically be ensured when using the `using` statement with the NetworkStream variable - would flush and thus send any as of yet unsent data lounging in some send buffers...)

Comment: What determines the end of the data?  You are using string request = reader.ReadToEnd() which will read the current data in the receive buffer and not wait until all the data is received.  There are too solutions.  Add a end character that is not part of the actual data and then loop and read until you find the end character.  Second solution is to add a byte count at beginning of transmission and then at receive end read byte count and then read data until you get all the bytes by using the count.  A network stream will add a end to the send file and then you can check the stream for EOF.

Comment: I implemented flushing, closing of stream and made it so it doesnt read to end instead a line each time. And tried with telenet and server gives back response. The java code seems to be failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by removing writer.close() cause that causes socket closing and makes another connection to the server by creating again the socket which makes the server wait for a stream of data and the client wait for a response...

```
        System.out.println("Sending data...");
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        writer.println(message);

        InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry , I can't comment. maybe you can use `telnet` command to vertify c# code is corrent.

```bash
telnet ip port
```

first, locate problem, then solve it.

if server is ok , we can use `nc` command vertify client code, I have test your java code , except every send data will close socket , other is ok.

Comment: Hey I tried with telnet and everything is okay... I connect, send a line, server recieves it and sends back Server and connection is lost then. Maybe my code on the java side is bad since the server works?